# 503 Service UNavailable

Tags: codeigniter-3, cpanel, web-hosting, http-status-code-503

Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The other link of my webpage are working fine. The only page that is not working contains information or data. Including Add and modifying of records.

The problem occurs when the webhost server migrate to new server.
Does rebooting the server help me to resolve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does a lot of query affects the web page? or having an 100 thousand rows in the db and displaying it in the view page.